# Ruby on rails: JSON::ParserError and 500 Internal Server Error with instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http

I am using the instagram ruby gem. If i do more than 2 requests below is what the error i get.

Now, for the first two request it shows this

```
Processing by HomesController#index as JS
Processing by HomesController#index as */*
```

So when the third request happens now, it erros into (as said above) this

```
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4525ms

JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="hl-en not-logged-in ">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page Not Found &bull; Instagram</title>

    <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex" />

    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/images/ico/favicon.ico" />

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />



        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/scripts/bluebar.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/cache/strings/strings_en.js"></script>
        <script>
window._csrf_token = 'NOTPROVIDED';
window._jscalls = [


];
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/cache/polyfills/polyfill_old.js"></script>
<script data-main="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/cache/modules/main.js" src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/scripts/require.js"></script>





        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/cache/bluebar/bluebar_new.css" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/f4f8a28/cache/distillery/dialog-main.css"/>


</head>
<body class=" p-error dialog-404">

<div class="root">


    <div class="page">


                <header class="top-bar top-bar-new">
    <div class="top-bar-wrapper">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="/">Instagram</a></h1>

        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="top-bar-actions">
                <li>
                    <a class="top-bar-home" href="/" label=Home><i></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="top-bar-search" id="top-bar-search">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-bar-right account-state" id="top_bar_right">
            <ul class="top-bar-actions">


                <li id="link_profile" class="link-signin">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="loginLink">
                        <i></i>
                        <strong>Log in</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>


          </div>
    </div>
</header> <!-- .top-bar -->




        <div class="main">

    <div class="error-container">


    <h2>Page Not Found</h2>

    <p>This page could not be found.<br />You might have followed an incorrect link.</p>


    </div>

        </div> <!-- .main -->


    </div> <!-- .page -->


    <footer class="page-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/about/us/">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://help.instagram.com/">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://blog.instagram.com/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/developer/">API</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/jobs/">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/legal/privacy/">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/legal/terms/">Terms</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <p class="copyright">&copy; 2013 Instagram</p>
        </div>
    </footer>



<div id="reactModalMountPoint"></div>
</div> <!-- .root -->







<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18105282-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>

</body>
</html>'
```

I think something is wrong with the header? Since I am doing the process via ajax, how can I force it to process it through JS? since thats what seems to work here I believe.

Here is my ajax code

```
{
            $.ajax({
            url: /home,
            method: "post",
            data: {
                // data goes here
            },
            success: function(html)
            {
                if(html)
                {       

                            // html goes here
                }else
                {
                   // html goes here</center>');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instagram is blocking your request if you do to many request in a specific time

Answer (score 0):

Instagram is serving up an error page instead of the JSON you expect.  You need to check the response's status code (in this case it would be 404 instead of 200) to find out if the payload is JSON or HTML in the case of the error page.

Answer (score 0):

After so much work on this, I found out for my case that it is because something in the content of the JSON data is screwing things around. That was my situation (and I hate how 500 status is so vague about the error, too)